# How to minify Less file output?

Tags: css, less

I'm using Less files with Bootstrap for my application and also using  Less for client-side CSS compiling. I'm wondering how I can minify the compiled CSS output with Less.

I think I need to declare something in between above lines.

Comment: Hmm, there's absolutely no point in minifying CSS client-side. What for?

Comment: @seven-phases-max this is required when you want the users be able to customize the website dynamically

Comment: @Anirudha You don't need to *minify* or anything like this for *client-side* CSS result.

Answer (score -2):

Most popular tools for task automation are [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). Both can assist you in your minification.

But to use your `less` files you have to convert them to `.css`.

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-less to convert your `less to css` and then minify then using https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-cssmin.